# Do damage to the enemy

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a 2D, Top-Down game in progress.

I want to be able to apply damage to the enemy when I press space bar and the enemy is within a certain distance of the player.

At the moment the code moves the enemy slowly towards the player and applies damage to the player once they collide. When I hit space bar the enemies are destroyed but I want the damage to be applied ONLY WHEN THE ENEMIES ARE CLOSE to the player.

Here is my enemy code currently, with a health system set-up:

```
var Player : Transform;
var MoveSpeed = 4;
var MinDist = 5;
var Health = 100;
var anyValue = 100;

function Update () 
{
  transform.LookAt(Player);

  if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) >= MinDist)
  {
      transform.position += transform.forward*MoveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
   }
{
  if(Health <= 0)
  {
      Dead();
  }

}
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) < someValue &&    Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
{
  ApplyDamage(someValue);
}
}

function ApplyDamage (TheDamage : int)
{
  Health -= TheDamage;
}

function Dead ()
{
  Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Comment: It's worth stating explicitly what's not working in your code.

Comment: Nothing is not working. I just want to learn how to apply damage to the enemy when a button is pressed within a certain distance.

Comment: Try researching a little, this question is too vague for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

To apply damage within a certain distance I needed this:

```
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) < 1.25 
    && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
{
   ApplyDamage(5);
}
```